# Performance of Cos vs. Sqrt(1 - Sin() ** 2)

Tags: performance, optimization, fortran, sqrt, trigonometry

I am computing a lot of `cos(x)`'s in my program. Is it more efficient in Fortran to stick with `cos(x)` or to calculate `sqrt(1-sin(x)**2)`? Will I be sacrificing any accuracy if the `sqrt` method is more efficient? And, I guess, the most important question if `sqrt` is more efficient. Can I expect that the compiler is recognizing this anyways and changing it for me?

Comment: In general, there is no reason to believe that `sin` and `cos` have different throughput. They likely even share most of their code inside the math library. Have you measured their respective performance and found otherwise?

Comment: The authors of the compilers and the math libraries know these transformations as well as you do, unless there's something special about your use cases that you can exploit.  Making these micro-optimizations chew up your time and make the code harder to read - don't do them unless (a) you've profiled the code and you see that cos() execution time is a major bottleneck (in which case, well done) and (b) it actually makes a difference big enough to be worth it - something that is easily quantified with simple tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should note is that you'll have to be careful to pick the correct root for `sqrt(1 - sin(x)**2)`, otherwise you run the risk of evaluating `|cos(x)|`, which is not the same. That itself adds complexity.

Use `cos(x)` as you should avoid such perceived micro-optimisations: you'll do well to beat any optimisation approach adopted by a modern FORTRAN compiler.

Even when I was using FORTRAN, the clever FORTRAN compilers would use the trig functions available on a chipset. `sqrt` is still on the whole implemented with a Newton-Raphson type algorithm and its evaluation will take a handful of clock cycles.

My hunch is that the latest compilers *would* reverse out your identity for you and substitute `cos(x)`: check the output assembly.

But if you are in any doubt, profile it.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure whether the compiler would ever switch between `cos(x)` and the identity. Unless `x` is constrained between `-pi/2` and `pi/2` or the positive `cos` ranges, switching to the identity would force the answer to always be positive and would produce incorrect results.

Comment: Additionally, the identity may produce a slightly different result due to floating point error, which typically restricts optimizations.

Comment: @Ross Ahhh thank you. That's what I was afraid of and was part of my question. Any idea of the error magnitude?

Comment: @Higgy Forget about the error, just use `cos` it must be faster than this compound expression for sure.

Comment: If you are hoping to see compiler optimization where you have sin() and cos() of the same value, your compiler may be able to recognize applicability of a sincos function in its library.  You would see this if you profiled, which is an important step to take anyway before complicating your code in the interest of optimization.  In some older versions of gcc, the automatic substitution of x87 sincos into vectorizable SSE code was counter-productive.